# Create/Delete Space seperated folder names

Tags: php, imap, dovecot

When I try to create a folder whose name is seperated by spaces it only takes the first word and ignores the second one. How do I solve this? I am writing with php to a dovecot sever. The space seperator given by LIST is "/".

The Code:

```
private const NEWLINE  = "\r\n";
private socket = fsockopen("ssl://testmail.com", 465, $errno, $errstr, 
20);
$foldername = "Hello World"
function createFolder($socket, $foldername) {
fputs($socket, "A3 Create " . $foldername . self::NEWLINE)

return read($socket);}

function read($socket)
{

stream_set_timeout($socket, 30);
$lines = [];

while(\FALSE !== ($line = fgets($socket))) {
    $lines[] = $line;

    if (\FALSE !== strpos($line, 'BAD')) {
        break;
    }

    if (\FALSE !== strpos($line, 'NO')) {
        break;
    }

    if (\FALSE !== strpos($line, 'OK')) {
        break;
    }

    if (\FALSE === strpos($line, 'OK')) {
        continue;
    }
}

return $lines;}
```

I have tried escaping strings and write it in a different way, but nothing seems to work. It does create a folder, but as mentioned above only with the first word.
Server reply:

```
array(1) {[0]=>string(25) "A3 OK Create completed."}
```

edit: Here are some of the things I tried out, once by modifing the fputs and then while playing around with the string:

```
fputs($socket, "A3 Create " . \$foldername . self::NEWLINE)  Result: HTTP ERROR 500
fputs($socket, "A3 Create " . '$foldername' . self::NEWLINE) Result: $foldername
fputs($socket, "A3 Create " . "$foldername" . self::NEWLINE) Result: Hello
fputs($socket, "A3 Create " . '\$foldername . self::NEWLINE) Result: \$foldername
fputs($socket, "A3 Create " . 'Hello' . 'World' . self::NEWLINE)   Result: HelloWorld
fputs($socket, "A3 Create " . 'Hello ' . 'World' . self::NEWLINE)   Result: Hello
fputs($socket, "A3 Create " . "Hello " . "World" . self::NEWLINE)   Result: Hello


$foldername = "'Hello World'";         Result: 'Hello
$foldername = '"Hello  World"';        Result: Hello
$foldername = 'Hello World';           Result: Hello
$foldername = "'Hello \ World'";       Result: 'Hello
$foldername = "<<<EOD Hello World EOD";  Result: <<<EOD
$foldername = '<<<EOD Hello World EOD';  Result: <<<EOD
$foldername = <<<EOD Hello World EOD;  Result: Hello
$foldername = "%Hello  World%";        Result: %Hello
$foldername = '%Hello  World%';        Result: %Hello
$foldername = '\Hello  World';         Result: \Hello
$foldername = "\Hello  World";         Result: \Hello
```

Comment: Where is that method invoked in your code? The code you've provided prints `A3 Create`, while the example response you've posted prints `A3 OK Create` - are you sure you've posted the proper code?

Comment: Yes. The "OK" comes from the server reply, it prints "OK", "BAD" or "NO" at the last line it responds with. I do not print `A3 Create` but the fgets the reply my server gives me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Works: 
`$foldername = '"Hello\\ World"';`

Answer (score 0):

Enclose it in quotes so that you send:

```
A4 CREATE "Folder Name"
```

PHP is not my language, but presumably, something like `$foldername = '"Folder Name"'` will get you what you want.

Comment: Nah, thats not it. I edited my main post to include results of the things I have tested.

Comment: In not one of your attempts, do I see you sending double quotes to the server.  I see lots of `"'...'"` to send single quotes to the server but not `'"..."'` to send double quotes.  It looks like PHP accepts either `' '` or `" "` as quotes itself.  Single quotes mean nothing to IMAP.

Comment: I did not know that IMAP does not accept Single Quotes, thanks for that info. However I did test it and edited it above. Unfortunately it just created "Hello" again.